# json =>json is not a know variable in the current context<

Tags: json, netbeans

I am working on a project where I need to process JSON string and to test it I write the following code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        String res=null;
        res= "{\"array\":[{\"title\":\"21 new minister join PM narendra modi's gov , shiv sena boycotts oath ceremony\",\"cat\":\"academic\"}]}";
        out.print(res);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res);

        out.print(json);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

I already check the string **res** at http://pro.jsonlint.com/ and it approved this String.
I also debug the code and set the breakpoint at **out.print(res)** and it's working fine and then goes to **out.close()** without throwing any Exception. The debugger message is same as title "json =>json is not a know variable in the current context<"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass your json data to the calling area as response then you need to change

```
out.print(json);
```

to

```
out.write(json.toString());
out.flush();
```

Comment: no working... as i said debugger is not come over

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(res);

this line